# How to get or set value to specify UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, iboutlet

Halo, I am a beginner in programming, and I start to learn Objective c now !

```
for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
        y += 50;
        x = 160;

        for (int j=0; j<9; j++){
            grid = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50 , 50)];
            grid.layer.borderWidth = 1;
            grid.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [[self view] addSubview:grid];

            x += 50;

            grid.text =  [@(j) stringValue];

            [initialArray addObject:grid];

        }

    }
```

I tried to using these code to for-loop many UITextField.

and each grid has a number, and I put the grid into a NSMutableArray

but how can I set a value to specify field? is it has a id for me to do this?
and how to get the value from field when the button is clicked?
thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a string

```
 grid.text=@""some value";
 [initialarray objectAtIndex:i].text=@"some value";
```

Getting value

```
 NSString *str=grid.text
 NSString *str=[initialarray objectAtIndex:i].text;
```

You can set tag by simply giving

```
grid.tag=i; 
[initialarray objectAtIndex:i].tag=i;
```

i can be a loop variable.

Comment: thanks, but how to setting a string to specify grid.tag ?

Comment: you can assign integer value as tag till now. If you need make an NSMutable array and save index as tag

Comment: thank you ! last question,  can I add 2 tag ? because I need to control the grid value by  2D array

Comment: NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3]; so you can save 3 values at all index paths. [dataArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"tag1",@"tag2",@"string value",nil] atIndex:i]; and save index as tag.

Comment: I mean the index for 2D array, just like java array[8][8], its simple to do this, how can I create array[8][8] using objective c ?? there is no index after I created.....I can not get or set the value from the array...

Comment: you can create 2d array using..  id array[lnum][rnum]; and use it as any other arrays array[i][j]=yourValue;   you can assign any type value into this type of array

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


if (textField==yourTTextField) {
NSString *strText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

if ([strText isEqualToString:@"$"] == TRUE) {

    textField.text = @"";
    return NO;
}
if (strText.length ==1) {

    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@", strText];
    return NO;
}
}
return YES;
}
```